# JSP POST Script to recieve AWS SNS confirmation message?

Tags: post, amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-sns

I am implementing AWS SNS functionality. The endpoint that I have defined is a URL(jsp) of a web page with HTTP Protocol I want to write a POST script which would receive the message from AWS SNS and accept the confirmation.